# java.net.UnknownHostException Error

Tags: java, sockets

so im getting this error when my server is sending some information over to my already connected clients when a new client connects. I've stepped through the code and the unknownhostexception error occurs at the line surrounded by asterisks;

```
            String temp1 = inputMessage.substring(4);
            String [] newString = temp1.split(",");
            System.out.println(newString[0] + " " + newString[1] + " " + newString[2] + " " + newString[3]);
            **InetAddress newAddress = InetAddress.getByName(newString[2]);**
            int port = Integer.parseInt(newString[3]);
            ClientConnectionInfo user = new ClientConnectionInfo(newString[1], newAddress, port);
```

Can someone tell me why and how to solve this issue?

Edit: so you know, because of the way ive done things im converting a string back into an inetaddress so i can construct a class.

Comment: Print newString[2] to console/log and make sure it is reachable machine name (or) IP. How to check reach-ability? use ping statement from command line

Comment: could you elaborate, new to java and netbeans hah :D

Comment: 1) Use System.out.println(...)  (or) debug mode to make sure value in that index is what you want 2) If value is correct, make sure you can talk to that machine by typing ping in ms-dos command prompt.

Comment: the value of it is /127.0.0.1 - so can that function not support the / so i need to remove it?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. As learner, remember that System.out (or) debugger will be your friend to overcome these hurdles.

Comment: Yeah just added a replace function and its working perfectly now, cheers mate.